# jQuery loaded data not firing modal like it should

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Okay, I have a map of the country, the user clicks on their state, and a bunch of suppliers is loaded through jQuery via a page like this:

```
$('#sa').click(function () {
    $('#mapimg').hide();
    $('<div id="info">&nbsp;</div>').load('dealers.php?state=sa', function () {
        $(this).hide()
            .appendTo('#dealers')
            .slideDown(3000);
    });
});
```

Then when it displays the deals, I want the user to be able to click the 'contact us' next to each dealer and have a modal jump up with a contact form in it. But it doesn't seem to be firing. on clicking just does nothing.

Here is the jQuery code to trigger the modal box:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a').click(function (e) { //I have tried everything here, div, a[name=something], li, etc
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
        $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });
});
```

The following code works outside the loaded content, but not inside. Did anyone get any ideas?

```
<a href='#dialog2' class='openmodal'>Open Modal Box</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the dynamically loaded content you just need to juse live bindings. Please use [jQuery live events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live). Suppose contact link has class "clsContact" then you can put dialog opening login in function "OpenModal" and bind links like this:

```
$("a.clsContact").live('click', OpenModal);
```

Comment: worked great. thanks! just a side note: that live was not implemented until jQuery v1.3.. this caught me out for a little while, but got it sorted in the end =]